# Is there a function in python to number the time an item appears in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-manipulation

I am trying to check when a client appears in my dataframe to do some logic with other results. However, I am unable to number when the customer appears. I've gotten the first and last time it appears, I just can't get it in the intervals between the first and last time. Could you please help me? Here is an example table, I want column C as the result.

```
Date    Customer    Appear
01/01/2021  A   1
01/01/2021  B   1
01/01/2021  C   1
01/02/2021  A   2
01/02/2021  B   2
01/02/2021  C   2
01/03/2021  A   3
01/03/2021  B   3
01/03/2021  C   3
01/04/2021  A   4
01/04/2021  B   4
01/05/2021  A   5
01/05/2021  B   5
01/06/2021  A   6
```

[image]

Comment: What is an expected output?

Comment: Use `df['Appear'] = df.groupby('Customer').cumcount().add(1)`

Comment: @SangkeunPark expected output is column C (Appear)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `groupby` with `cumcount`

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('Customer').cumcount()+1
Out[202]: 
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     2
6     3
7     3
8     3
9     4
10    4
11    5
12    5
13    6
dtype: int64
```

Comment: ouch, it is not for answer...

Comment: its work, like @mozway post:
df['Appear'] = df.groupby('Customer').cumcount().add(1)